# Write to a file with multiple jobs in PowerShell

Tags: windows, powershell, parallel-processing

We have an activity that runs the following code:

```powershell
$nr = $WorkflowData['_Number']

## Write to text
$nr>>C:\Configuration\nrFile.txt
```

Basically it gets a unique number that should be added to a file. 
The problem is that this activity runs in multiple workflows that can run at the same time. 
This resulted in a lot of errors saying that the `nrFile.txt` is opened by another job running at the same time.

Is there some way to write from multiple workflows to the same file simultaneously?

Or maybe to queue them up somehow?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could synchronize file access using a Mutex e.g.

```
$mutex = new-object System.Threading.Mutex $false,'SomeUniqueName'
...
nr = $WorkflowData['_Number']
$mutex.WaitOne() > $null
$nr >> C:\Configuration\nrFile.txt
$mutex.ReleaseMutex()
```

Comment: I've used this technique to synchronize access to IIS configuration to allow us to run multiple deploy scripts at the same time and avoid the dreaded "Cannot commit configuration changes because the file has changed on disk"

Comment: Works great! I'm using this with both PowerShell 5.1 and PowerShell 7.

Answer (score 2):

You alternate between saying multiple **jobs** are trying to access the file, or multiple activities in a **workflow**.  Jobs are isolated into separate processes, so certain contention-prevention mechanisms do not apply.  Workflows are run within the same process, so those approaches could be appropriate in that case.

It's not glamorous, but a basic "if at first you don't succeed, try, try again" approach is usually perfectly adequate for something like this.

```
filter append
{
   param(
       [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, ValueFromPipeline = $true)][string[]] $line,
       [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, Position = 0)][string] $path
   )

   $done = $false
   while(-not $done)
   {
       try{ $line | out-file $path -append -ea Stop }
       catch { sleep 1; continue }
       $done = $true
   }
}

$nr | append C:\Configuration\nrFile.txt
```

**Edit**
Previously incorrectly asserted that named mutex (Keith's approach) does not work inter-process.

Comment: Mutexes work across processes.  In fact, that is their primary purpose. Perhaps you're thinking of Monitors or Semaphores. Try a Mutex (same name) from two different PowerShell consoles.  Works just fine as long as the consoles are STA (and not MTA).

Comment: I stand corrected.  Unnamed mutexes do not work cross-process, but named ones (like your example) do.  Thanks for pointing out my error, I've edited my answer.

Comment: No worries.  I wouldn't want to count the number of corrections I've had to make on SO.  :-)